Is there a difference between blocking the platform thread vs pinning in virtual thread?
In JEP 444 , I could see the following statements when talking about  blocking operation

The implementations of these blocking operations compensate for the capture of the OS thread by temporarily expanding the parallelism of the scheduler

Then 2 sentences below when explaining about pinning

The scheduler does not compensate for pinning by expanding its parallelism.

Therefore does it mean pinning is a special variant of blocking?
Why does expanding parallelism won't help in case of pinning?
Are synchronized  or native only possible pinning operations or they are just 2 among other possible cases?


Therefore does it mean pinning is a special variant of blocking?

No.  Absolutely not.  A virtual thread is pinned when it does something that would make thread switching by the the scheduler impossible.  These things can happen at any time.
In this context, pinning matters if the virtual thread blocks.  But it is not a "form" or "variant" of blocking1.

Why does expanding parallelism won't help in case of pinning?

What the quoted text actually means is that the scheduler does not add new carrier threads if a virtual thread is pinned.  It says that doesn't expand parallelism.
It is moot whether it would help if the scheduler spontaneously created carrier threads.

Are synchronized or native only possible pinning operations or they are just 2 among other possible cases?

Foreign function calls are the other case.  These are the cases listed in the JEP, and the Virtual Threads documentation. in Java 21.  There is no reason to disbelieve the official documentation2.

1 - Any more than getting a flat tyre, or stopping at traffic lights is a "variant" of riding a bicycle!
2 - I haven't checked the OpenJDK source code to be 100% sure.  But even if I did, the analysis would only be valid for the particular Java source code snapshot that I was looking at!


It says that doesn't expand parallelism.
Why does it expand parallelism in other blocking case?


Because when a virtual thread that is not pinned gets blocked, the scheduler can reschedule the carrier thread to another virtual thread ... effectively allowing the second virtual thread to run in parallel with the blocked virtual thread.


Why does it expand parallelism in other blocking case?
here I meant the case where virtual thread won't unmount from the carrier thread.
IIUC, JEP mention 3 kind of blocking cases 1 The normal one where virtual thread blocked  by some kind of  IO where it will get unmounted from the carrier thread 2 Where virtual thread will be blocked but it can't be unmounted from the carrier thread but in this case scheduler can expand the parallelism 3 VT get pinned and parallelism can not be increased. Is my understanding wrong about 2 &3


Oh I see what you are asking.  You would need to ask the designers the real reason, but my guess is that in those cases there nothing that a programmer could reasonably be expected to do to solve the problem.  By contrast, the programmer can avoid pinning by (for example) not calling long-running native methods, etc from a virtual thread.

I think, the logic behind the decision is that the implementation will create new threads for known scenarios where the creation of new threads is likely to help. In contrast, the other group mainly consists of unpredictable scenarios. When you invoke a native method, the thread gets pinned and it’s not clear whether it will block at all or in case it blocks (which is even hard to detect for native methods), it’s not known whether it will be for a long time.
